# Calling onclick rich tab to place cursor in a textfield

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsf

My requirement is to place the cursor on a field whenever a rich tab is navigated to.
I tried `onclick` and `onlabelclick` on the `richtab`, it doesn't help. I tried using `ontabenter`, it called my Javascript function below

```
function placeCursor() {
    jQuery("#send\\:emailAddress").focus();
    return false;
}
```

however, the cursor is not shown on the field.

If i call the same Javascript function from `onclick` of the `richTabpanel` that the tab is under it works and the cursor is placed. However, the `onclick` is called every time I click inside the tab. So even when I click on the next text field this Javascript is called and my cursor is moved to `emailAddress` field.

Answer (score 1):

To debug the first thing you can do is output the length of the jquery query:

```
console.log(jQuery("#send\\:emailAddress").length)
```

If the number == 0 then you know the query failed. jQuery does not return null when querying, rather an array-like object + $.fn so that it can execute whether or not it found an element.

Comment: I believe whts happening is since the tab is not yet rendered by then, it doesnt find the field to place the cursor. What can I do to call the javascript after the tab is rendered so that it finds the object to place the cursor.